# Bootstrap tab Multiple form submission by using form id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tabs for forms. Each tab has form id. I want to submit form by using form id. My form submission works fine. When I click tab 5 times,it will send data to server 5 times. That's my problem.Also first tab form is not submitted during document on load
My html code is attached below:
Here is my code: 
http://www.bootply.com/asHAcXeSby

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
  <li class="active"><a href="#academic" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"> ABC</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#extra" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> DEF</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="academic" class="tab-pane fade active in">
    <form role="form" method="post" action="" id="academic_dtls">
      <input name="xyz" type="text">
      <input name="submit" value="Save" type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="extra" class="tab-pane">
    <form role="form" method="post" action="" id="extra_dtls">
      <input name="mnz" type="text">
      <input name="submit" value="Save" type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var activeTab = null;
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (event) {
    activeTab = $(event.target).attr("href");
    submit_form();
  });
  function submit_form(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //alert($(this).attr('id'));
      var data = $(this).serialize();
      console.log(data); 
  });
  }
});
```

Comment: Show your code here.

Comment: Bootply link is in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this: http://www.bootply.com/fCNm9iQ7t1
The mistake you were doing was you were binding the submit event every time the tab was showing

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var activeTab = null;
   $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (event) {
     activeTab = $(event.target).attr("href");
   });
  $('form').submit(function(e){
      var data = $(this).serialize();
      console.log(data); 
  });

});
```

Comment: It works fine on fiddle but in my application form id is not working without tab initialization. Firstly I was using same approach as you described. When it's not working, then I using the method as I described

Comment: May be there is some jquery conflict. Try giving class to form and then call function

Comment: I use different class in form but it didn't work. When form tag is initialized before tab, then your method works fine but when form tag is inside tab,it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //alert($(this).attr('id'));
      var data = $(this).serialize();
      console.log(data); 
  });

  var activeTab = null;
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (event) {
    activeTab = $(event.target).attr("href");
  });

});
```